# Camera2 ImageReader hangs after a while with "Failed to release buffer" message

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I'm having a problem with android's camera2 API. 
My end goal here is to have a byte array which I can edit using opencv, whilst displaying the preview to the user (e.g. an OCR with a preview). 
I've create a capture request and added an ImageReader as a target. Then on the OnImageAvailableListener, i'm getting the image, transforming it to a bitmap and then display it on an ImageView (and rotating it).

My problem is that after a few seconds, the preview stalls (after gradually slowing down) and in the log om getting the following error: **E/BufferItemConsumer: [ImageReader-1225x1057f100m2-18869-0] Failed to release buffer: Unknown error -1 (1)**

As you can see in my code, I have already tried closing the img after getting my byte[] from it.
I've also tried clearing the buffer. 
I've tried closing the ImageReader but that of course stopped me from getting any further images (throws an exception).

Can anyone please help me understand what im doing wrong? I've been scouring google to no avail.

This is my OnImageAvailableListener, do let me know if you need more of my code to assist:

```java
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener
            = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

            Image img = reader.acquireLatestImage();
            final ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.camPrev);

            try{

                if (img==null) throw new NullPointerException("null img");
                ByteBuffer buffer = img.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                byte[] data = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                buffer.get(data);
                final Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        iv.setImageBitmap(b);
                        iv.setRotation(90);
                    }
                });
            } catch (NullPointerException ex){
                showToast("img is null");
            }finally {
                if(img!=null)
                    img.close();
            }
        }
    };
```

Edit - adding cameraStateCallback

```
private CameraDevice.StateCallback mCameraDeviceStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
            showToast("Connected to camera!");
            createCameraPreviewSession();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            closeCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice cameraDevice, int i) {
            closeCamera();
        }
    };

    private void closeCamera() {
        if (mCameraDevice != null) {
            mCameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: It seems your code for this part is right, but can you change `buffer.remaining()` to `buffer.capacity()` and tell me the results ? I already implemented camera2 once and I used capacity as I remember.

Comment: Also are you closing the cameraDevice after reaching onPause() ?

Comment: Can you post your stateCallBack part code ?

Comment: Sure, adding the cameradevice stateCallBack, along with closeCamera
Regarding the onPause, Im calling the same closeCamera function along with a stopBackgroundThread that is supposed to later on do the processing itself. 

BTW maybe its important to mention that im OPENING the camera device only on onWindowDocusChanged and not on onResume or onCreate ( as I have discovered that both of them sometime try to load whiel the ImageView is still null and couldn't find out how to make some sort of state listener for the ImageView ( like the one texture view has)).

Comment: I have also tried to change to buffer.capacity but unfortunatley it didnt help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have used `setRepeatingRequest()` for Jpeg format. This may not be fully supported on your device, also depends on the image resolution that you choose. Normally, we use `createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)` in these cases, and get YUV or raw format from ImageReader.

I would try to choose low resolution for Jpeg: maybe this will be enough to keep the ImageReader running.

Comment: Thank you. The thing is that i want the camera to continuously feed images to the image reader to create a processable preview, until an event occurs. Will your solution answer this need?

Comment: It should. What do you mean by words *processable preview*, I don't exactly understand.

Comment: Lets say I want to get the image from the camera, grayscale it and only then show it on the ImageView. Just pre-process it before displaying it to the user.

Comment: If you want to convert the camera input to grayscale, YUV should be your choice.

Comment: Theres several other processing steps i want to do. Iwill test your solution and update. Thank you!

Comment: Be careful not to perform heavy image processing on the Camera thread! Also, consider using a Surface for your output, because ImageView was not designed to be updated very often.

Comment: I've gone with the proposed method of showing the preview on a surface. 
Now that I have that surface, I need to get the images off of it and preprocess it before sending them to an OCR script I have. 
What is the acceptable way of doing that? I've currently added a getBitmap in the OnTextureUpdated listener but Im not sure its the best way... 
What I would really want is just a way to get "between" the camera output to the preview surface, so I can edit the images before they are displayed..

Comment: Better get YUV images from camera via ImageReader. OnTextureUpdated is not necessary.